# Extracting min and max value of Django model feature in template

Tags: javascript, django

I have a model like this:

```
class Integer(models.Model):
    integer_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    share = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    market = models.ForeignKey(
        IntegerMarket,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='integers',
        default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.integer_value)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['integer_value']
```

I'm using the following view:

```
class IntegerMarketDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = IntegerMarket
    template_name = 'integer_market_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

In my template, which is for a given instance of `IntegerMarket`, I would like to extract the minimum and maximum values of `integer_value`, in order to then define the min and max value of an axis in JavaScript.

For example, I might have an instance of `IntegerMarket` featuring five `integers`, with `integer_value` 1 through 5, respectively. I would then like to extract 1 as min and 5 as max.

What's the most straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Is this template for the detail of a single instance of Integer, or a list of many? What kind of view are you using?

Comment: Thanks, @DanielRoseman. The template is for an instance of `IntegerMarket`. Each instance of `IntegerMarket` will have several instances of `Integer` (i.e., `integers`, per the related name) associated with it. I've added the view in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an instance `integer_market` of `IntegerMarket`, you can get all the related `Integer` instances using `.integers` since you nicely set that as `related_name`.

Now you can just do an aggregation using `Max` and `Min`.

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min
integer_market.integers.aggregate(Max('integer_value'), Min('integer_value'))

>> {'integer_value__max': 10, 'integer_value__min': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks, dirkgroten! But is there a way to pick it up as (say) 10 as opposed to `{'integer_value__max': 10}` on the template side? That way, I can feed it straight into the javascript using double curly braces.

Comment: That’s the rerurn value I was showing. It’s a dictionary with the keys `integer_value__max` and `integer_value__min`

Comment: So if you pass it as context variable `v` to your template you can use `{{ v.integer_value__max }}` to have the value in your HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

Django offers max and min values to be defined in queries.

from django.db.models import Max, Min

Then when defining your query you'll have something like

```py
my_query = models.IntegerMarket.objects.all().annotate(max_integer=Max('integer_value')).annotate(min_integer=Min('integer_value'))
```

Then you can call those values in your view using max_integer/min_integer or whatever you named it.